# Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p>5$, $e\in \{1,2,3,4,6\}$, and $K_e$ be a totally ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of ramification index $e$.

If $K_{e'}$ is another Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of ramification index $e$, then how to prove there exists a finite unramified extension $M$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ such that $MK_e=MK_e'$?

More general, if we only assume $K_e$ is an finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of ramification index $e$(not a totally ramified extension), do we have the same conclusion?

Remark: We fix an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and we do all of these in it.

Thanks!

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Of course, we fix an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ at first, I have edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: If $p \nmid e$ it is easier. Do you see why ? ($\pi_K^e = p u, u \in O_K^\times$)

Comment: @reuns Yes, $p\nmid e$, I hope that you can give more details and give it as an answer below!

Comment: I wrote a lot of answers about those things, for $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ totally tamely ramified of degree $e$ its uniformizer satisfies $\pi_K^e = p u, u \in O_K^\times$ and $O_K = \Bbb{Q}_p[\pi_K]$ (ring of power series in $\pi_K$..) and $u$ (binomial series or Hensel lemma) has a $e$-th root in $O_{K(\zeta_e)}^\times$ thus $p^{1/e} = \pi_K u^{-1/e}$ is an uniformizer of $O_{K(\zeta_e)}$ and hence $K(\zeta_e) = \Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_e,p^{1/e})$.